# Church tax capital gains tax exemption

Tags: capital-returns

My understanding is that churches in the United States, as they are non-profit organizations, are exempt from pay tax which includes capital gains tax. If one were to start a church that had all the qualifications of a church such as member, a place of worship and a doctrine, could the "church" act as an investment company for non-church members that avoids paying tax?
If not, what measures are put in place to avoid such schemes, If so why isn't this more prevalent?
Thanks

Comment: This far off topic IMO.